# Backspaces deletes the whole anchor tag in content editable

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, contenteditable

I have a div which is content editable. This editor contains an anchor tag.

when I press backspace from the end, everything works as expected in chrome. It deletes the character one by one and deletes the whole anchor tag when all the content is deleted.

But in IE, the moment I press the backspace from the last cursor position, it just deletes the whole anchor tag itself. Basically, the link is gone but the text is there.

How to make it work similar to chrome?  I have searched for other question in SO but couldn't find any answers.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.editor {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='editor' contenteditable=true>
  <h1><a href="#">Some text</a></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of IE? IE11?

Comment: @mkaatman IE 11